# How can I use multiprocessing in python to monitor the coordinates of a robotic arm?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I used the code below to print my `x` and `y` coordinates at the same time of the execution of `Move_Relative()`. It seems that the Move Relative function is not executed because at the end of execution my output is (`x = 0` and `y = 0`). What am I doing wrong?

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
import sys

x = 0
y = 0


def monitor_coordinates():
    global x
    global y
    print("x: " + str(x) + " y: " + str(y))
    
    
def Move_Relative():    
    global x
    global y
    while x < 100000:
        x = x + 1   
        y = y + 0.5

if __name__=='__main__':
   
    q = multiprocessing.Process(target = Move_Relative) 
    q.start()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target = monitor_coordinates)    
    p.start()
    
    q.join()
    p.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are not shared between processes. One *good* alternative is using `multiprocessing.Value`

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value
import sys

x = Value('d', 0)
y = Value('d', 0)


def monitor_coordinates(x, y):
    print("x: " + str(x.value) + " y: " + str(y.value))


def Move_Relative(x, y):
    while x.value < 100000:
        x.value = x.value + 1
        y.value = y.value + 0.5


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = multiprocessing.Process(target=Move_Relative, args=(x, y))
    q.start()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=monitor_coordinates, args=(x, y))
    p.start()

    q.join()
    p.join()
```

output:

```
x: 88826.0 y: 44413.0
```

Comment: It solves a part of my problem. The other part is that the values of `x` and `y` are not printed at the same time of the loop execution. If it was the case I would get several output lines with `x` and `y` incremented until the loop condition is broken.